# What command will generate average lines per minute?

Tags: bash, command-line

I'd like to know how many average lines are written to a file per minute.

Comment: Could you be more explicit?  E.g., does there need to be a running LPM status, or is just a calculation at the end sufficient?  Is this wall-clock time, CPU time, etc.?  Do you have a specific definition of "line"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
tail -fn0 the-file | pv -lri60 > /dev/null
```

That will give you a number of lines per second though.

Otherwise:

```
{
  cat > /dev/null
  while sleep 60; do
    wc -l
  done 
} < the-file
```

(beware that won't be exactly accurate as the `sleep 60` won't guarantee that is done exactly every 60 seconds).

Comment: So where is the averaging done?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, in the `wc -l` done on the last lines added within the last 60 seconds.

Comment: @Stephane, so it's a count, not an average.  But perhaps that's what the OP really wanted.

Comment: First works for me; just changing lri60 to lri1 gives immediate feedback :-)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas How do you use `grep` in between `tail` and `pv` to filter output? It's not working for me..

Comment: @kouton use --line-buffered to prevent grep from buffering. see also the stdbuf command